# Check the type of a field received by reflection, and perform an action

Tags: c#, reflection

To simply state, I just recently got into using reflection. While trying write code that could automate previously repetitive tasks for me, I came across a problem. I cannot correctly understand how to access the field that reflection returns to me as a `FieldInfo`. Here is my current code:

```
class cClass
{
    // these classes implement the IClass interface
    public static aClass _aClass = new aClass();
    public static bClass _bClass = new bClass();
}

// in another class
public List<IClass> aList = new List<IClass>();
public void init(cClass theClass)
{
    theClass.GetType()
        .GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(field =>
        {
            if (field.FieldType == typeof(aClass))
                aList.Add(field) // this doesn't work, because FieldInfo doesn't inherit IClass
                aList.Add((aClass)field); // This doesn't work because I cannot cast
            // if bClass, then something similar
        });
}
```

How would I be able to check the type, and add it, potentially by casting the `field` which reflection has given into the type I check against. (I dislike using multiple `if` statements, so a switch statement would be better off)

e.g:

```
if (field.FieldType == typeof(aClass))
    aList.Add((field as aClass));
```

Comment: Note that you don't need to tag this `game-engine`, since it doesn't appear as though expertise in game engines is needed to answer it. It is likely better to tag it with `reflection`.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan changed.

Comment: In this case, you want to get the value of the field, correct? `FieldInfo` has a method, [`GetValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.fieldinfo.getvalue?view=netframework-4.7.1) that gets the value of the field, which would have a type of `aClass`.

Comment: You might find the answers to [Cast to a reflected Type in C#](//stackoverflow.com/q/18052562) educational as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Create a helper function

This will allow you to reuse the code later on, or allow others to easily implement it.

```
public static void ForEachFieldIn<C>(C theClass, BindingFlags theFlags, Action<FieldInfo> task) where C : class
{
    theClass.GetType()
        .GetFields(theFlags)
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(task);
}
```

## Different check conditions

If you know the field type

```
ForEachFieldIn(ourClassInstance, BindingFlags.Public, BindingFlags.Instance, field =>
{
    var theField = (theKnownType)field.GetValue(null);
    // do stuff
});
```

If you have no clue what the field *specifically* may be

```
ForEachFieldIn(ourClassInstance, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance, field =>
{
    if (field.FieldType == typeof(someClass))
        // do some stuff
    if (field.FieldType == typeof(otherClass))
        // do other stuff
});
```

For my specific example, since both classes inherit from the `interface` *IClass*, I can simply use the first option, since I know the field type.

As for casting the field, simply use `field.GetValue(null)`, and cast that from an `object` into whatever you like, provided you perform necessary checks first.